# recv() not receiving the number of bytes expected

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, winsock, recv

The issue I'm having right now is regarding:

```
int k = send( hAccepted, p, size, 0 );
```

'p' is a buffer containing some file, an mp3, text file or what have you. The issue is that if the file in question is say '5,000,000' bytes, send() will return 5,000,000 every time it is called, even if the receiving end did not receive all 5,000,000 bytes. This is making it quite difficult to debug on the server side, as the client is fully aware it did not receive the whole file, but the server is quite convinced that it sent the whole thing.

Comment: How did you open the socket? If you are using TCP then it should not complete the `send` (successfully) without the other end receiving the content. If you use UDP, then you need to add code in the receiving side to "tell" you how much data it received.

Comment: It's all TCP. The first thing that is sent to the client is the file size in bytes (which gets sent correctly), the client then sets up a buffer of that size to receive the file, then send/recv is called again. Send ALWAYS returns that the full file was sent, recv essentially gets different numbers every time.

Comment: @Yelnik How do you receive the data ? With TCP, it might take _many_ receive calls to receive the result of 1 send() call.

Comment: I hope that you are aware that the TCP protocol does not guarantee any particular grouping of data during delivery. Your `recv` can be "receiving" things a byte at a time, or 5 megabytes at a time. You have to keep receiving until all the data is there.

Comment: @MatsPetersson That's not correct. send() only transfers to the socket send buffer. Writing to the network is asynchronous. The send() can return before all the data is received by the peer. The send() can return before *any* data is received by the peer.

Comment: Also, `send`'s return value has little to do with what happened at the protocol level. It simply lets you know whether *at the time of the call* the data was *accepted for sending*. It *does not* mean that the sending has succeeded - even though in your case it did succeed, only you don't call `recv` properly (it seems).

Comment: On the client side, I can run 'recv' until the return value == the size of the file, but then it seems like it just loops continuously receiving completely different chunks of bytes.

Comment: As everybody has been telling you, the recv() method isn't obliged to fill your buffer. It's only obliged to transfer at least one byte, or return zero or -1. You have to loop, and until the *total* transferred == the expected size! much as in your send loop.

Comment: The recv is currently inside a while loop until the return value is equal to the size of the file: http://pastebin.com/JjABt98d

But does this just not continuously try to receive the entire file until it happens to be the whole thing? And again, the issue with looping on the send() side is there isn't really any value to check for. I can't really make the terminating condition that send == file size, since it == file size every time.

Comment: That's not adequate or even correct coding. If you read part of the file in one recv(), how can a following recv() ever transfer the total length of the file? Read my last comment again.

Comment: @Yelnik: Read EJP's comment again.  You need to loop until the **total** number of bytes equals what you are expecting. The return value of `recv()` is *NOT* the **total** number of bytes received, only the bytes received *for that specific call* to `recv()`.  You have to keep track of the **total** yourself, adding the return value of `recv()` to the **total** on each loop iteration until the **total** reaches the desired value.

Comment: Ok I am going to attempt something like this: http://pastebin.com/rtc232Nu


Thanks for all the replies by the way

Comment: Please don't. Have a look at the code in my answer. Your version doesn't work if there is an error.

Comment: I think it may be working, however I am confused about one thing: while the 'recv' is looping, does the send() also have to be looping? Or does it not matter once the send() has but all the data into the socket buffer (i.e. send() returned the file size).

Comment: If send() returns the expected value, you're done. See also my comment to @RemyLebeau under my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

send() returns the number of bytes transferred to the socket send buffer. If it returns 50,000, then 50,000 bytes were transferred. If you didn't receive them all, the problem is at the receiver, or in the network.

You would have to post some code before any further analysis is possible.

Probably you're expecting to receive all those bytes in a single recv() call. It isn't obliged to do that by its specification. You have to loop:

```
char buffer[8192];
int length = ... // number of bytes expected;
int total = 0;
int count;

while (total < length && (count = recv(socket, buffer, min(sizeof buffer, length-total), 0)) > 0)
{
    write(outfd, buffer, count);  // or do something else with buffer[0..count-1]
    total += count;
}
if (count < 0)
{
    perror("recv");
}
```

Or else you've done an abortive close at the sender which discards data in flight.

Or you got an error during recv() and didn't detect it in your code.

Or ...

Comment: Right now the send is something like this: http://pastebin.com/Pn9AwHHi

Mind you, this is completely redundant, because it'll pass on the first attempt (since send always returns the same value as 'size').

The receiving code is something like:http://pastebin.com/JjABt98d

Comment: Please edit the *receiving* code into your question.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The send() loop you edited in isn't really necessary. I know it's specified the same way as recv(), but all known implementations block until all data has been transferred to the socket send buffer. There was a discussion about this in news:comp.protocols.tcp-ip where all the implementors are, and they all agreed, and someone also came up with some Posix wording that makes it mandatory. Sadly I forget the details.

Comment: Based on what you just the EJP, the way send() works is that it essentially only needs to be called one time, assuming it returns the value of the file size?

Comment: If someone still answers this that would be great: are zips/rars etc. expected to maintain themselves when being transferred? So far sending mp3's seems generally fine, but with zip's, it will SOMETIMES extract SOME of the files inside (which oddly remain intact), while saying the zip is corrupt.

Comment: ..then you still have a bug.

Comment: @EJP if a program is blocked in a large send() call, and a signal (e.g. SIGINT) is received, what does send() do?  (if it returns -1/EINTR, then the TCP connection is likely unusable after that, since the program will not know how many bytes were sent and thus can't know what to send next.  If send() doesn't return at all, then the thread remains blocked in send() and can't respond properly to the signal.  The only remaining option is for send() to return the number of bytes it actually sent, which I believe it what it does, newsgroup discussions notwithstanding)

Comment: Are you closing the file when recv() returns 0?

Comment: @EJP: I have seen `send()` exit without sending everything it was given. And Jeremy is right that a SIGINT can also cause `send()` to exit prematurely. So it is good practice to loop both `recv()` and `send()`.